# Which alternatives exists for WebRTC getUserMedia given the incompatibility with IOS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, getusermedia

Forgive me if the question is bad, but I developed a streaming service for work using WebRTC getUserMedia on the front-end and connected it with Socket.IO on NodeJs, that has problem only with iPhones and Safari on MacOS. Looking on Stack Overflow and other forums I understood that happens because it is not compatibile. So my question is what can I use alternatively?

Do I need to use a JavaScript library like ReactJS or another?

Comment: What problems exactly?  iOS supports WebRTC https://caniuse.com/rtcpeerconnection

Comment: doesn't show my camera or connected users. According to that you sent, all versions of IOS supports WebRTC? because they are very likely to use old versions of IOS

Comment: The link I added says that 11+ is supported which was released [June 19, 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_11).  If you need to support something older than that, you would need a full library solution.  ReactJS won't help you, it's not a multimedia streaming or P2P library.  Asking for library recomendations is off-topic for this site.  You would need to do some searching for some WebRTC alternative to fit your requirements.  We can help you with issues that you have with that library, but not with picking which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies not with getUserMedia(), but with MediaRecorder. iOS, and indeed Safari in general, doesn't handle MediaRecorder correctly.  (Is Safari taking over from IE as the incompatible browser everybody loves to hate?)

I was able to hack around this problem by creating a [MediaRecorder polyfill](https://github.com/OllieJones/mediarecorder-jpeg-polyfill) that delivers motion JPEG rather than the webm usually made when you code video. It's video-only, and generates cheezy "video" at that.

If you put the index.js file for this at `/js/jpegMediaRecorder.js` you can do something like this.

```html
<script src="/js/mpegMediaRecorder.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      function handleError (error) {
        console.log('getUserMedia error: ', error.message, error.name)
      }
      function onDataAvailableHandler (event) {
        var buf = event.data || null
        if (event.data && event.data instanceof Blob && event.data.size !== 0) {
          /* send the data to somebody */
        } }
      function mediaReady (stream) {
        var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
          mimeType: 'image/jpeg', videoBitsPerSecond: 125000, qualityParameter: 0.9
        })
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', datahandler)
        mediaRecorder.start(10)
      }
      function start () {
        const constraints = {
          video: { width: {min: 160, ideal: 176, max: 640},
                   height: {min: 120, ideal: 144, max: 480},
                   frameRate: {min: 4, ideal: 10, max: 30} },
          audio: false }
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(mediaReady)
        .catch(handleError)
      }
      start()
    })
</script>
```